# GWT Programatically Save Panel to Image

Tags: gwt, panel, screenshot

I would like to be able to save the contents of a decorator panel into some sort of image format. Does anyone have an ideas of how i could either take a screen shot and save it or some how export a panel to an imae format?

Comment: You mean like the content of a panel showing in your browser and programmatically in you gwt application take a screenshot and send it to the server?

Comment: Ya, Either send it to the server or save it to the desktop of the clients computer

Comment: I don't think that it's possible, as it would be a major security leak, because it would allow to make a malicious injected program that would take a screenshot of some sensitive data on your web page.

Comment: Here is another SO question that should help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: one can do it via svg, checkout highcharts export js file

Answer (score 0):

Try using html2canvas. GWT Panel is just a html  element with some javascript to handle the layout.

You can find html2canvas here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/